# Can MapKey be unique to one relation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entities:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="_user_id")
    @MapKey(name="quest")
    private Map<String, ActiveQuest> activeQuests = Maps.createHash();

    ...

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"_user_id","quest"}))
public class ActiveQuest implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="_user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable=false,updatable=false,length=50)
    private String quest;

    ...
```

The documentation for `@MapKey` says:

> If a persistent field or property other than the primary key is used
>   as a map key then it is expected to have a uniqueness constraint
>   associated with it.

However, as you can see there is no unique constraint on the column `quest` of `ActiveQuest`, but there is one on the combination `_user_id, quest`.

Is this usage correct? It appears to work well, but is that by design or just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that looks fine - you do actually have a "uniqueness constraint" associated with it since you're joining on user_id and using quest as the key, and user_id+quest is unique...

Comment: I think what Bart has done is fine, i think your analysis is correct, and i think this is a flaw in the MapKey javadoc.

Comment: FWIW, the JPA2 spec, in 11.1.27, says "If a persistent field or property other than the primary key [of the target entity] is used as a map key, it is expected to be unique within the context of the relationship", which i think more clearly matches what Matt says.

Comment: Ok then. I was afraid that maybe an implementation would leave out the `_user_id` when fetching because according to the `MapKey` documentation it should be able to use only `quest`.